# How to make html tags responsive to layout size adjustments?

Tags: html, css, d3.js, svg

I probably have too much of content here for what I am trying to do. I basically just want to make my layout constraints to carry over to varying window sizes. Unfortunately, the layout doesn't carry over and certain HTML tags are cut off on smaller screens. How do I make the layout consistent across all screen sizes?

For reference, the layout of the page should look like this:

```
 ----------------------------------------
|  [div 1]                               |
|                                        |
|                                        |
|                ----------              |
|                |   svg  |              |
|                ----------              |
|                                        |
|  [button1]                  [button2]  | 
-----------------------------------------
```

The SVG has a border and uses a viewBox to allow the SVG to adjust sizing appropriately. However, this is a CSS and HTML issue as my other controls are not responsive.

This is probably very trivial but I think the viewBox might be affecting the HTML tags.

This is my HTML:

```css
#radioToggle {
  position: fixed;
  margin-top: -20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background: white;
}

#buttonOneDiv {
  position: fixed;
  padding: 20px;
  bottom: 0;
}

#buttonTwoDiv {
  position: fixed;
  padding: 20px;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}

#container {}

#tree {
  text-align: center;
}

svg {
  border: solid 2px black;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="radioToggle"></div>
<!-- this is div1 -->
<div id="container">
  <!-- container hosting the div that hosts the SVG-->
  <div id="tree"></div>
</div>
<div id="buttonOneDiv">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Back</button>
</div>
<div id="buttonTwoDiv">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" id="collapse">Forward</button>
</div>
```

For additional reference, here is my SVG:

```
let svg = d3.select("#tree")
.append("svg")
.attr("viewBox", "0 0 " + (width + margin.left + margin.right) + " " 
+ (height + margin.top + margin.bottom))
```

Comment: I think an SVG is self contained and its viewbox values shouldn't affect HTML outside of the SVG. Responsive web design is a big topic, you should maybe start by looking into media queries

Comment: Have you noticed that viewbox is not designed to handle dimensioning and positioning inside browsers?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: Can you explain more about this: `.attr("viewBox", "0 0 " + (width + margin.left + margin.right) + " " + (height + margin.top + margin.bottom))` Does your SVG change it's `viewBox` on resize? Who's `width` and `margin`?